# Passing string value one gui to another

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, jframe

[Main class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZrP1.png)

[Result GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zj1og.png)

I am trying to add one string from main class to another gui when you hit the submit button. When the second gui comes up however, it comes up null on my firstname.

class 1 main

```
public class SubmitButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        
        first_name = firstText.getText();
        last_name = lastText.getText();
        firstText.setText(first_name);
        lastText.setText(last_name);
        
        
        frame.setVisible(false);
        resultGui gui1 = new resultGui();
        gui1.setName(first_name);
        
    }
    
}
```

class 2 second gui

```
 public JFrame resultFrame;
    public JLabel first_name_label , last_name_label;
    private String first_name;
        
      public String getName() {
          return first_name;
      }
        
      public void setName(String name) {
          this.first_name = name;
      }
```

Comment: What does 'It comes up null on my firstname' mean? Plus you did not post the full code. The problem may be in the unknown parts.

Comment: You're not passing the first name to the second `JFrame`.  You should be using one `JFrame` and a `CardLayout`.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: You should include minimal, **REPRODUCIBLE** code. What you included here cannot be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class 1 you use `gui1.setName(first_name);`, which will invoke

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.first_name = name;
}
```

in class 2. But the value is not passed to the Label. That method probably should look like

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.first_name = name;
    first_name_label.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible answer.

Comment: this worked for me the way i wanted to actually

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the second GUI (let's call it a popup) as a component of the first. In the example below, I chose to make the popup an internal frame. Then, all the action listener of the "show popup" button needs to do is grab the text from the text field and set it on the label in the popup.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Form form = new Form();
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        pane.add(form, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class Form extends JPanel {
        private JTextField field = new JTextField();
        private Popup popup = new Popup();
        JButton btn = new JButton("Show popup");

        public Form() {
            field.setColumns(20);
            add(field);
            add(btn);
            add(popup);
            btn.addActionListener(e -> {
                popup.setLabel(field.getText());
                popup.setVisible(true);
            });
        }
    }

    private static class Popup extends JInternalFrame {
        private static final String TEXT_PREFIX = "You entered: ";
        private JLabel label = new JLabel(TEXT_PREFIX);

        public Popup () {
            super("Popup", false, true, false, false);
            add(label);
            label.setVisible(true);
            setLocation(0,0);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        }

        public void setLabel (String text) {
            label.setText(TEXT_PREFIX + text);
        }
    }
}
```

I added this code to Replit. You can run it from there. [Replit JInternalFrameDemo](https://replit.com/@HectorFontanez1/InternalFrameDemo?v=1)

See the results below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: i will think about using popup later in my  code thanks